# Xamarin passing arguments between pages

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to open a new `Page` on a tap event, which should display some detailed information on a certain object. For that to work, I need to pass the object itself or its ID to the new page. So I added an argument to the constructor of the detail page as follows.

```
void onItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item != null)
    {
        bool convOk = Int32.TryParse((string)e.Item, out int id);
        if (convOk)
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailPage(id));
        }
    }
}
```

And the `DetailPage` has its own `DetailViewModel`, which is set as the `BindingContext` within the code-behind.

`DetailPage` XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             x:Class="Foo.Views.DetailPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <Label Text="FooBar" />
            <Label Text="{Binding trackID}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

`DetailPage` code-behind

```
namespace Foo.Views
{
    public partial class DetailPage : ContentPage
    {
        public DetailPage(int trackID)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BindingContext = new DetailViewModel(trackID);
        }
    }
}
```

`DetailViewModel`:

```
namespace Foo.ViewModels
{
    public class DetailViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        // trackID prop
        int _trackID;
        int trackID 
        { 
            get { return _trackID; }
            set 
            { 
                _trackID = value;
                notifyPropertyChanged(nameof(trackID));
            } 
        }

        public TargetDetailViewModel(int tid)
        {
            trackID = tid;
        }
    }
}
```

However, the binding between the `DetailPage` and the `DetailViewModel` doesn't seem to work, the page doesn't show anything. The id itself is passed correctly all the way down to the `DetailViewModel`.

Is this due to the order of initialization? I presume that everything written in XAML will be executed in the `DetailPage.InitializeComponent()` method? If that's correct, is it safe/correct to instantiate the `ViewModel` before the `DetailPage.InitializeComponent()`?

Any hint appreciated.

Comment: Your `trackID` property is not `public`

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Now it works. I hate myself. Thank you very much!

Comment: We have ALL done it 

Comment: You can answer the question, so you get some credit!

Comment: Done, I added how to catch these binding issues a little faster

Comment: It happened again today :D I'm incurable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `trackID` property is not public.

**Note**: if you watch the application log output you can catch binding problems like this (filter it by the string `Binding:`)

#### Log example of a private variable not being bound:

```
Binding: 'trackID' property not found on 'XXXX.VM', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Label.Text'
```

#### DetailViewModel Fix:

```
public class DetailViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    int _trackID;
    public int trackID;
    { 
        get { return _trackID; }
        set 
        { 
            _trackID = value;
            notifyPropertyChanged(nameof(trackID));
        } 
    }
    ~~~~
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the log message, mate! I didn't know that. Have a good one :)